# How can I refresh cache after I add,delete or update a data?

Tags: android, android-studio, caching, retrofit, okhttp

Because when I inserted, removed, updated a data, the list of data has not been updated. Please help refresh the cache after modifying a data, so that the display list will also be updated after modifying.

My CacheInterceptor:

```
public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException
    {
        Response originalResponse = chain.proceed(chain.request());
        if ( Utils.isNetworkAvailable(context) )
        {
            int maxAge = 60; // read from cache for 1 minute
            return originalResponse.newBuilder()
                    .header("Cache-Control", "public, max-age=" + maxAge)
                    .build();
        }
        else
        {
            int maxStale = 60 * 60 * 24 * 28; // tolerate 4-weeks stale
            return originalResponse.newBuilder()
                    .header("Cache-Control", "public, only-if-cached, max-stale=" + maxStale)
                    .build();
        }
```

Display Data:

```
                    for(Result result : commitment.getResultlist())
                    {
                        Log.e("id", String.valueOf(result.getId()) );
                        Log.e("Title", result.getTitle());
                        Log.e("Description", result.getDescription());

                        textResult.append(String.valueOf(result.getId()) + " ,");
                        textResult.append(result.getTitle());
                        textResult.append(", " + result.getDescription() + "\n\n");
```

Inserting Data:

```
case R.id.btn_submit:
               myRetro.create(CommitmentApi.class)
                        .insertData("", edt_title.getText().toString(), edt_desc.getText().toString())
```